# How to write a custom FindElement routine in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to figure out how to write a custom FindElement routine in Selenium 2.0 WebDriver. The idea would be something like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Method( (ISearchContext) => {
  /* examine search context logic here... */ }));
```

The anonymous method would examine the ISearchContext and return True if it matches; False otherwise.

I'm digging through the Selenium code, and getting a bit lost. It looks like the actual By.* logic is carried out server-side, not client side. That seems to be complicating matters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do this. I'm leveraging driver.ExecuteScript() to run custom js on the webdriver. It looks a bit like this:

```
function elementFound(elem) { 
    var nodeType = navigator.appName == ""Microsoft Internet 
Explorer"" ? document.ELEMENT_NODE : Node.ELEMENT_NODE; 
    if(elem.nodeType == nodeType) 
    { 
        /* Element identification logic here */ 
    } 
    else { return false; } 
} 

function traverseElement(elem) { 
    if (elementFound(elem) == true) { 
        return elem; 
    } 
    else { 
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) { 
            var ret = traverseElement(elem.childNodes[i]); 
            if(ret != null) { return ret; } 
        } 
    } 
} 

return traverseElement(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do a multi-staged search.  I have a method that performs a try catch and then a method that gets the element.  In theory you could do a try catch until instead of this way but I like this way better because of my setup.

```
public bool CheckUntil(IWebDriver driver, string selectorType, string selectorInfo)
{
  int Timer = 160;
  bool itemFound = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < Timer; i++)
  if(itemFound)
  {
   i = 0
  }
  else
  {
   Thread.Sleep(500);
   if(selectorType.ToLower() == "id" && TryCatch(driver, selectorType, selectorInfo))
   {
     if(driver.FindElement(By.Id(selectorInfo).Displayed)
     {
      itemFound = true;
     }
   }
   else if(selectorType.ToLower() == "tagname" && TryCatch(driver, selectorType, selectorInfo))
   {
     if(driver.FindElement(By.TagName(selectorInfo).Displayed)
     {
      itemFound = true;
     }
   }
  }

  return itemFound;
}
```

Here's my try catch method you can add as many different types as you want id, cssselector, xpath, tagname, classname, etc.

```
public bool TryCatch(IWebDriver driver, string selectorType, string selectorInfo)
{
  bool ElementFound = false;

  try
  {
   switch(selectorType)
   {
    case "id":
     driver.FindElement(By.Id(selectorInfo);
     break;
    case "tagname":
     driver.FindElement(By.TagName(selectorInfo);
     break;
   }
   ElementFound = truel
  }
  catch 
  {
   ElementFound = false;
  }
 return ElementFound;
}
```